# Should create user account be an extend relationship from login?

Tags: uml

Right now I am trying to create a uml for a bank site and I am not sure how to relate create bank account and login to the user. I know you have to have an account in order to login but if the user already has one they don't need to create an account.Should create an account be an extention of login? The login use case connects to the actor customer. If anything is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model it in both ways: one having create account as an extension of login, and one where they are separate use cases. Both cases are correct, but the first one shows that if the user doesn't have an account he can create one in the login process and as part of it.